# php find two array values in result multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am looking for last three month state wise data.I have all state code array and last three month array with the following values,

```
$stateArray = array("Nj","va","Ca","BS","TS");
$MonthArray =array("Nov 2016","Dec 2016","Jan 2017");
```

Below is my result array fetch from the database,

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [month] => Nov 2016
            [count] => 150
            [state] => NJ
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [month] => Nov 2016
            [count] => 100
            [state] => va 
        ) 
    )
        I want result like below,

        Array(
                [Nj] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                     [month] => Nov 2016
                                     [count] => 150
                                    )
                        [1] => Array(
                                     [month] => Dec 2016
                                     [count] => 0
                                     )
                         [2] => Array(
                                     [month] => jan 2017
                                     [count] => 0
                                    ) 
                   )
               [Ca] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                     [month] => Nov 2016
                                     [count] => 0
                                    )
                        [1] => Array(
                                     [month] => Dec 2016
                                     [count] => 0
                                     )
                         [2] => Array(
                                     [month] => jan 2017
                                     [count] => 0
                                    ) 
                   )
                [va] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                     [month] => Nov 2016
                                     [count] => 100
                                    )
                        [1] => Array(
                                     [month] => Dec 2016
                                     [count] => 0
                                     )
                         [2] => Array(
                                     [month] => jan 2017
                                     [count] => 0
                                    ) 
                   )
            )
```

and so on for all states.

I am trying to array `array_search()` and `in_array()` functions for each but it is not working.What I would like to accomplish to loop each state wise array.Below I am trying for looping,

```
foreach ( $result_array as $val ) {
    $month = array_search ( $val ['month'], $monthArray );
    $state = array_search ( $val ['state'], $stateArray );
    if ($val ['count'] == '' || $val ['count'] == 'NULL') {
        $countValue = 0;
    } else {
        $countValue = $val ['count'];
    }
    $final_array [] = $countValue;
}
```

Comment: All such patterns are not valid php: `$val ['month']`. Remove the blank character between variable name and brackets.

Comment: ok,I removed this blank space but expected result not getting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'month' => "Nov 2016",
        'count' => "150",
        'state' => "NJ"
    ],
    [
        'month' => "Nov 2016",
        'count' => "100",
        'state' => "va"
    ],
    [
        'month' => "Dec 2016",
        'count' => "270",
        'state' => "NJ"
    ],
];
$output = [];
foreach (["Nj", "va", "Ca", "BS", "TS"] as $state) {
    $output[strtoupper($state)] = [];
};

array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[strtoupper($entry['state'])][] = [
        'month' => $entry['month'],
        'count' => $entry['count']
    ];
});

print_r($output);
```

The result of the above code is:

```
Array
(
    [NJ] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 150
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 270
                )

        )

    [VA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 100
                )

        )

    [CA] => Array
        (
        )

    [BS] => Array
        (
        )

    [TS] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

This appears to be the exact output structure you ask for.

Comment: We have set of state and moth.We have to loop each state with each month set.

Comment: @bhagwanpawar Sure, I understood that from your question. That example _does_ loop all entries in your given result set. Do you want to say that your result set does _not_ contain entries for all combinations of state and month? So you have incomplete data?

Comment: We want to append zero result set those are not in resultant array

Comment: yes arkascha, In result set does not contain entries for all combinations.We are not getting data for all month and state.Those month and state data not getting we set zero result set.

Comment: @bhagwanpawar Just add those emty default entries in your resulting array as shown in the updated answer...

Comment: @bhagwanpawar (I took the liberty to convert your state keys to upper case, since your data is inconsistent in that)

Comment: Thanks arkascha,this is close to my result.But we have to plot graph.I want to plot graph of last three month of each state count.So each state contain last three month and those state and month present in result will diplay in final array and those are not present show zero count for that month

Comment: So you want to add not empty arrays for the combinations  not present in your result set, but entries with the same structure, but a zero value (`0`) instead? Ok, sure, why can't you extend this solution for that, as I already did? Or do you insist on code you can copy&paste without modification? For that please hire a programmer. SO is _not_ a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

```
       $stateArray = array("Nj","va","Ca","BS","TS");
    $MonthArray =array("Nov 2016","Dec 2016","Jan 2017");
    $fromDB =    Array (
        Array (
            'month' => 'Nov 2016',
            'count' => 150,
            'state' => 'NJ'
            ),
        Array (
            'month' => 'Nov 2016',
            'count' => 100,
            'state' => 'va'
            )
        );
    $info = array();
    foreach ($fromDB as $row){
        $info[strtoupper($row['state'])][$row['month']] = $row['count'];
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($stateArray as $state){
        foreach ($MonthArray as $month){
            $result[$state][]=array('month'=>$month, 'count'=>isset($info[strtoupper($state)][$month])?$info[strtoupper($state)][$month]:0);
        }
    }
print_r($result);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [Nj] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 150
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Jan 2017
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

    [va] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Jan 2017
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

    [Ca] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Jan 2017
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

    [BS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Jan 2017
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

    [TS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Nov 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Dec 2016
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [month] => Jan 2017
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Андрей Танечник,This is what I want.Thanku u very much